# php regex to identify all HTML special chars in decoded string

Tags: php, html, regex, decoding

I expected to find this in SO already... but haven't so far

I'm talking about a regex which looks at an HTML ENCODED string: e.g. something like

```
blip &#9830; trout&rsquo;s mouth
```

Have I covered all the bases with `&\w+;` and `&#[0-9]+;`?

```
$encoded_string = htmlspecialchars($_GET["searchterms"]);
echo "<b>Search results for submitted string: \"$encoded_string\"</b><br><br>";
$html_special_chars_pattern = "!(&\\w+;|&#[0-9]+;)!";
$non_html_tokens = preg_split( $html_special_chars_pattern, $encoded_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the [`&#xH;` or `&#XH;` numeric character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1).

> 5.3.1 Numeric character references
>
> Numeric character references specify the code position of a character in the document character set. Numeric character references may take two forms:
>
> - The syntax "&#D;", where D is a decimal number, refers to the ISO 10646 decimal character number D.
> - **The syntax "&#xH;" or "&#XH;", where H is a hexadecimal number, refers to the ISO 10646 hexadecimal character number H. Hexadecimal numbers in numeric character references are case-insensitive.**

That is, `&#[xX][a-fA-F0-9]+;` in regular expression.

Comment: thanks... does that cover all HTML entities (references, whatever), as far as you know?

Comment: @mikerodent, as far as I know, yes

Answer (score 1):

I have put [my earlier related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13763250/1338292) as an answer here. If someone else comes up with a better solution or why it would break, do let me know :)

```
preg_match_all('/&(?:[a-z]+|#\d+);/', $content, $matches);
```

To support hexadecimal entities as well:

```
preg_match_all('/&(?:[a-z]+|#x?\d+);/i', $content, $matches);
```

Btw, `(?: ... )` is used to prevent memory captures. See also: [What does `?` mean in this Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890739/what-does-mean-in-this-perl-regex)

Comment: thanks... as you can see in the answer below, there appears also to be the question of the hexadecimal refs.  Also I'm trying to understand what function the "?:" sequence has in your regex...

Comment: @mikerodent, `(?:)` is a non-capturing group